# how to express "a baby expels food out of the mouth"?

Tags: word-request

see this picture [image]

The boy seems to expel food out of his mouth.

I don't think we use the word "**spit it out**" because when you spit you use some force. But when you expel food out of your mouth, you don't use much force.

how to express "**a baby expels food out of the mouth**"?

Answer (score 1):

**[Dribbles](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dribble)** may suit your purpose, though it's slightly more common to refer to the [liquid or food dribbling](https://www.webmd.com/parenting/baby/how-to-start-solid-foods#1) than the baby dribbling the liquid or food. See [ngram for food](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dribbled%20food%2Cfood%20dribbled&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdribbled%20food%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfood%20dribbled%3B%2Cc0) and [ngram for liquid](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dribbled%20liquid%2Cliquid%20dribbled&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdribbled%20liquid%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cliquid%20dribbled%3B%2Cc0).

Still, it would be fine to say either

> "The food dribbled out of the baby's mouth."

or

> "The baby dribbled food out of his mouth."

I think **spits out** would also be a good option. It doesn't necessarily indicate great force. To my ear, **expels** comes with a much greater sense of force than **spits out**--when I read your question title I thought it was referring to a baby projectile vomiting.

Comment: Dribbled food, mixed with saliva, runs down the chin. That baby is spitting.

Comment: You can say a child is dribbling. Perfectly normal.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, but then it generally just refers to drool.

Comment: Drool is American, dribble is British in this context. Saliva, food, a mixture.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Dribble is used in Am. E. Dribble as a noun or verb by itself is generally understood to mean drool. When paired with another noun (food, liquid, etc), then obviously it refers to whatever is being discussed.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal to say a baby "spits it out" and not mean that they spit with the force you'd assume an adult would if they were described as spitting.

"Dribbling" is more descriptive, but can imply a liquid is being expelled, and is far less common than the phrase "spit it out" when talking about children or babies.